# Django: Filter by latest() with reverse foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to make the following `get_queryset` more efficient, but I'm not sure how to get there.

I need a list of Visits, each one being the first for a user. The following works, but is horribly inefficient:

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...


class Visit(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='visit_set')

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'date'
    ...
```

views.py

```
class SomeListView(ListView):

    # Get a queryset of visits, each is a first() for a user.
    def get_queryset(self):
        users = User.objects.filter(visit_set__isnull=False)
        visit_ids = [u.visit_set.earliest().id for u in users]
        return Visit.objects.filter(id__in=visit_ids)
```

How can I make this run without hitting the database for each user?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113494/how-to-optimize-a-sort-based-on-latest-related-model/51113637#51113637) do what you want?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use `.first()`? Since you did not specify any order for `Visit`, this means it will simply return *a* `Visit`, this can be the oldest, newest, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. Right, it is suppose to be earliest(). I added get_latest_by to the Visit model as well to complete the example.

Comment: @DanielRoseman. Thanks, that leads me in a new direction to try.